# What can I use to create html page-per-chapter/monolithic-page/pdf reference manual?

Tags: html, pdf, documentation, reference, manual

I want to write a reference manual for a project, and I want to make it available both online as a **HTML** one-page-per-chapter manual (optionally single-monolithic-page would be nice as well) and as **PDF** version.

Prime examples:

- The Gentoo Handbook ([html one page per chapter](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml), [html monolithic](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?full=1))
- Netty's user guide ([html one page per chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/html/index.html), [html monolithic](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/html_single/index.html), [pdf](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/pdf/netty.pdf))
- Spring's reference docs ([html](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/index.html), [pdf](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/spring-reference.pdf))

What can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's docbook + maven plugins (maven-jdocbook-plugin).

This [pom](http://github.com/brunodecarvalho/hotpotato/blob/master/pom.xml) contains a sample on how to produce what I intended in the first place.

The results can be found [here](http://hotpotato.factor45.org/#documentation).

There's also an alternative (still using docbook and maven), [docbkx-tools](http://code.google.com/p/docbkx-tools/).

Comment: Marking my own answer as right feels so... wrong ^^

Answer (score 1):

[HTMLDOC](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1).

HTMLDOC takes one- or multi-file HTML input and converts the input into PostScript, PDF or indexed HTML. Unless you require full CSS support, this is a good tool for the type job you want get done. You'd...

- ...author, maintain and version-control your documentation chapter-wise in HTML and
- ...then convert to PDF or indexed HTML as needed with the help of HTMLDOC.

AFAIK, the LDP (Linux Documentation Project) generates its PDFs that way.

(I'm sure you've already investigated how *netty.pdf* and *spring-reference.pdf* were generated (*jDocBook plugin for Maven* and *FOP/apache*), so I won't add any details about these.

Comment: Actually I'm having kind of a hard time with jdocbook-plugin... I'm new to maven, their page is quite scarce on documentation and I have yet to find a howto. So yeah, you could add plenty of details on those :)